# Move a Folder between 2 libraries inside 2 different sites will raise this error "Missing or mismatched field definition on the destination list

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate

I have 2 document libraries inside 2 different sites:-

1. The source library contain a custom column named Year of type Single Line of Text.
2. The Destination library is based on the built-in document library without any custom column

Now when i use the "Move Folder" built-in action to move a folder from source to destination i got this error:-

[image]

```
body":{"status":400,"message":"Missing or mismatched field definition on the destination list for source field 'Year' type 'Text'. Source site template id 'SitePagePublishing', target site template id 'GroupWebTemplateID'. Total blocked root objects in this operation is [1].\r\nclientRequestId: fd527fec-8893-4cf9-b62a-48b83d0eade2\r\nserviceRequestId: fd527fec-8893-4cf9-b62a-48b83d0eade2"}}
```

so from the error i think the issue is that the destination library is missing the Year column, although if we do the move using the UI we can move the folders. so any advice how we can do the move using power automate similar to how the UI work?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, the issue is because of column mismatch in 2 document libraries. Easier solution will be to add the column > move folder > delete column later. Else you will have to use "Create folder" action to create new folder instead of "Move folder" action. Let me know it it works for you

Comment: @GaneshSanap but using the UI we can move folders even if the source and destination does not have the same meadata

Comment: Yes, I know. But this is issue with the Power Automate flows while using Move folder or Move file actions.